# Closing and opening my app goes straight to homepage without verifying the user email

Tags: ios, xcode, authentication, swift4, email-verification

When I create a new user it does everything it should do and saves the users detail and goes back to the login page waiting for the email to be verified before allowing it to be used. The coding works so it doesn't allowing you to proceed until email has been verified but I've realised when I slide the app to close it and then reopen it (before verifying the email), it goes straight to the homepage bypassing the login page even if the email hasn't been verified?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import SwiftKeychainWrapper

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

var userUid: String!

override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    func Keychain() {
        KeychainWrapper.standard.set(userUid, forKey: "uid")
    }

    if let _ = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "uid"){
        LoggedIn()
    }
}

func goToCreateUserVC() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "CreateAProfile", sender: nil)
}

func LoggedIn() {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "LoginSuccessful", sender: nil)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "CreateAProfile" {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? CreatUsers {
            if userUid != nil {
                destination.userUid = userUid
            }
            if emailField.text != nil {
                destination.emailField = emailField.text
            }
            if passwordField.text != nil {
                destination.passwordField = passwordField.text
            }
        }
    }
}

func DisplayAlertMessage(MessageToDisplay: String) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: MessageToDisplay, preferredStyle: .alert)

    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in

        // Code in this block will trigger when OK button tapped.
        print("Ok button tapped");

    }

    alertController.addAction(OKAction)

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
}

@IBAction func signIntapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion:
            {(user,error) in
                if let user = Auth.auth().currentUser {
                    if user.isEmailVerified {
                        self.userUid = user.uid
                        print("Email Verified")
                        self.LoggedIn()
                    } else {
                        self.DisplayAlertMessage(MessageToDisplay: "Need To Verify Email Address")
                    }
                } else {
                    self.DisplayAlertMessage(MessageToDisplay: "Incorrect Username/Password")
                }
        });
    }
}

@IBAction func NotaMemberisTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    self.goToCreateUserVC()
}
```

}

Only happens when I close the app and reopen it to find it cheats its way through - trying to figure out how to prevent it from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re calling your LoggedIn() function based on whether or not there is a value in the keychain. I’m assuming you’re saving that information to the keychain whether or not validation has been performed.

Comment: yeah I've just put the condition into that aswell and it worked thanks alot 